# Data during "late binding" is not displayed on the real device (Xamarin.Forms + Prism + CarouselViewController)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

**Hello!** The code I give below works fine on an IOS simulator, but does not work on a real device (Iphone 6S Plus) - the tag collection (what it is in my case - you look further) does not fill out. (Xamarin.Forms, IOS project, Prism, CarouselViewController)

I apologize in advance for a large amount of code - this is part of a large program being developed, I immediately decided to bring all the necessary listing.

---

1.There are `PageA/PageAViewModel` (linked BindableBase (Prism)), `PageB/PageBViewModel` (linked BindableBase (Prism)) and logical `ViewModelС`. On `PageAViewModel` a logical `ViewModelС` is created and transmitted to `PageBViewModel` as a navigation parameter:

```
async Task GoPageB()
{
    var navigationParams = new NavigationParameters();
    navigationParams.Add("ViewModelС", ViewModelС);
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(new System.Uri("http://.../PageB",
                    System.UriKind.Absolute), navigationParams);
}
```

2. In the course of executing the code, it is collected by `PageB`, then its `PageBViewModel`, then it works out the `PageB` method of receiving navigation parameters in which the `PageBViewModel` receives the `ViewModelC`:

```
public override void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    var modelInParameters = parameters["ViewModelC"] as ViewModelC;
    MyViewModelC = modelInParameters;
}
```

3.`ViewModelC` is in `PageBViewModel` as a property, while in the constructor it is not declared, but is primarily obtained and assigned in the `OnNavigatingTo` method

```
public ViewModelC MyViewModelC
        {
            get => _myViewModelC;
            set => SetProperty(ref _myViewModelC, value);
        }
```

4.`PageB/PageBViewModel` is actually an onboarding built on `CarouselViewControler` (https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView). In XAML, it looks like this:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <abstractions:CarouselViewControl x:Name="OnBrdngPg_CrslVwCntrl"
                                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                          Orientation="Horizontal"
                                          InterPageSpacing="0"
                                          IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                                          IndicatorsTintColor="{StaticResource ClrGreyLight}"
                                          CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="{StaticResource ClrLightorange}"
                                          AnimateTransition="True"
                                          Position="0"
                                          ShowIndicators="True"
                                          ShowArrows="False">
            <abstractions:CarouselViewControl.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
                    <ContentView x:Name="CW1"/>
                    <ContentView x:Name="CW2"/>
                    <ContentView x:Name="CW3"/>
                    <ContentView x:Name="CW4"/>
                    <ContentView x:Name="CW5"/>
                </x:Array>
            </abstractions:CarouselViewControl.ItemsSource>
        </abstractions:CarouselViewControl>
 </ContentPage.Content>
```

5. `CarouselViewControl` in `x:Array` includes five `ContentViews`. Each of `ContentView` has five variants of views (the implementation of the Statecontainer - five states of one page  *Normal, Loading, Error, NoInternet, NoData*  - the page state is set in the code depending on the program logic, in XAML the Statecontainer subscribes to the state change and shows the corresponding `ContentView`:

```
<ContentView x:Name="CW2"
                Style="{DynamicResource ContentViewBoardingStyle}"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ClrGeneralwhite}">
                <ContentView.Content>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.Children>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                                              Style="{StaticResource StLt_BaseStyle}">
                                    <StackLayout.Children>
                                        <Images:ImageFit Source="{Binding HeaderImageSource}"/>
                                    </StackLayout.Children>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <stateContainer:StateContainer State="{Binding OnBoardingInState}"
                                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                                               Style="{StaticResource StateContainerNormalStateStyle}"
                                                               BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ClrGeneralwhite}">
                                    <stateContainer:StateCondition State="Normal">
                                        <stateContainer:StateCondition.Content>
                                            <StackLayout x:Name="OnbdngPg_RootStack2"
                                                         Orientation="Vertical"
                                                         Spacing="12">
                                                <StackLayout.Children>
                                                    <StackLayout Padding="0,15,0,10">
                                                        <StackLayout.Children>
                                                            <labels:LblLvl2 Text="{markupExtension:Translate OnBrdPg_Pg2_HdrTxt}"
                                                                    TextColor="{StaticResource ClrGeneraldark}"
                                                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                                                        </StackLayout.Children>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <StackLayout>
                                                        <StackLayout.Children>
                                                            <custom:GdyStackPanel x:Name="CustomControl"
                                                                                  CustomViewModel="{Binding ViewModelC, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                                                        </StackLayout.Children>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </StackLayout.Children>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </stateContainer:StateCondition.Content>
                                    </stateContainer:StateCondition>
                                    <stateContainer:StateCondition State="Error"/>
                                    <stateContainer:StateCondition State="Loading"/>
                                    <stateContainer:StateCondition State="NoInternet"/>
                                    <stateContainer:StateCondition State="NoData"/>
                                </stateContainer:StateContainer>
                            </Grid.Children>
                        </Grid>
            </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

6. As you can see on `CW2`, there is a `CustomControl` - this is a custom `Grid`, among other things, having a tag cloud - a collection of buttons that it generates from the `ObservableCollection  CustomControlTagsCollection`, located in `ViewModelC` (in control it is BindableProperty `CustomViewModel`).

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CustomViewModelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(CustomViewModel),
            typeof(ViewModelC),
            typeof(CustomControl),
            null,
            BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    var panel = bindable as CustomControl;
                    var oldbinding = oldValue as ViewModelC;
                    var newbinding = newValue as ViewModelC;

                    if (oldbinding == null)
                    {
                        panel.CustomViewModel = newbinding;

                        panel.ButtonNewTag.BindingContext = newbinding;
                        panel.EntryNewTag.BindingContext = newbinding;
                    }
                 // This method collects the tag cloud from the collection.
                    panel.CreateStackPanelAsync();
                });
            });


        public ViewModelC CustomViewModel
        {
            get => (ViewModelC)GetValue(CustomViewModelProperty);
            set => SetValue(CustomViewModelProperty, value);

        }
```

**SUMMARY**

Summarizing, we can say that:

- `PageA/PageAViewModel` transmits `ViewModelC` on `PageB/PageBViewModel`, which receives `ViewModelC` as a "navigation parameter"a method `OnNavigatingTo` (originally in the constructor `PageBViewModel` `ViewModelC` not defined in `PageBViewModel` as public property `PageBViewModel` originally initialized and is in `OnNavigatingTo`method). For this reason,`PageB/PageBViewModel` is initially built
  without `ViewModelС`
- respectively `PageB/PageBViewModel` → `CarouselViewControler` →
  `ContentView x:Name:"CW2"` → `CustomControl` at initial initialization receives an empty `CustomControlTagsCollection` and the tag cloud is not going to
- when `PageB/PageBViewModel` receives `ViewModelС`, along the path `PageB/PageBViewModel` → `CarouselViewController` -> `ContentView x:Name="CW2"` → `CustomControl` receives the transmitted `ViewModelС`, it executes the `propertyChanged BindableProperty CustomViewModelProperty`, the binding is updated and the `panel.CreateStackPanelAsync ()` method is called, which fills the collection with tags. In a sense, this "late binding".

---

I would appreciate any help.

I apologize for Google Translate.

Good and clean code to all of you (us :))!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello!**

I solved my problem in the context of working with Prism:

1. I replaced the logical model `ViewModelC` with `ServiceC`, at the same time I created `IServiceC` and `ServiceC`, registered them in `App.xaml.cs`:

   `containerRegistry.Register<IServiceC, ServiceC>();`
2. All the logic of work from ViewModelC was transferred to `ServiceC`.
3. Interested ViewModels that work with `ServiceC` data implemented it:

   ```
   //Declaration
   private IServiceC _serviceC;
   //Initialization 
   public ViewModelB(ServiceC serviceC)
   {
       __serviceC =  serviceC;
   }
   ```
4. In ViewModels, where `ServiceC` is required for binding through xaml, implemented it like this (**not sure if this is correct in terms of security**):

   ```
   //Declaration
   private IServiceC _serviceC;
   public IServiceC  ServiceC
   {
      get => _serviceC;
      set => SetProperty(ref _serviceC, value);
   }
   //Initialization 
   public ViewModelB(ServiceC serviceC)
   {
       ServiceC =  serviceC;
   }
   ```
5. BindableProperty in CustomControl:

   ```
   public static readonly BindableProperty serviceCProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
       nameof(MyServiceC),
       typeof(ServiceC),
       typeof(CustomControl),
       null,
       BindingMode.OneTime,
       propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
       {
           var panel = bindable as CustomControl;

       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
       {
           var oldbinding = oldValue as ServiceC;
           var newbinding = newValue as ServiceC;

           if (oldbinding == null)
           {
               panel.MyServiceC = newbinding;

               panel.ButtonNewTag.BindingContext = newbinding;
               panel.EntryNewTag.BindingContext = newbinding;

               //This is where the panel is filled with tags
               panel.CreateStackPanelAsync();
           }
       });
   });


   public ServiceC MyServiceC
   {
       get => (ServiceC)GetValue(ServiceCProperty );
       set => SetValue(serviceCProperty, value);
   }
   ```

   6. When exiting the viewmodels, implemented the Destroy method (for reasons of avoiding memory leaks):

      ```
       public override void Destroy()
      {
      base.Destroy();
      this.ServiceC = null;
      }
      ```
6. **Result** - everything works fine on the simulator and on the real
   device.

**Findings**:

1. I realized that when working with Prism and designing the view / viewmodels data exchange logic with third-party essential entities, it is not necessary to try to implement these entities through classes that are declared in viewmodels (`MyClass myClass = new MyClass () {}`), and then pass links or clones of this class between viewmodels - this leads to confusion and possible loss (timely underload) of data at one of the stages.
2. If my further studies of the security and performance of services in Prism confirm the assumption of stable and resource-saving work, I recommend this way.
3. I would be grateful for any advice, comments and advice on this matter.
4. **Thank you all!**